# When to use Factory design pattern instead of Dependency Injection?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory

I'm quite inexperienced in design patterns and while I was studying them I got confused about the application of the Factory pattern. Wouldn't DI decouple the classes more than factory would do it? Or would it be overkill to use DI in some situations? I understand DI as a step beyond Factory in decoupling by implementing IoC.

Comment: Do you really mean "DI", or do you mean a "DI container" (as an alternative to a factory)?

Comment: @DocBrown, I’d argue that the container *is* a factory. A factory is something that returns eg an object for a given set of criteria, which is what the container does.

Comment: @DavidArno: that's exactly my point - a (hand-written) factory instead of a "DI cointainer", that kind of question makes sense to me. "DI vs factory" is something I don't understand, these are orthogonal things. Voting to close as "unclear" until the OP clarifies what they mean.

Comment: @DocBrown I actually misinterpreted both patterns as focused mostly in decoupling, so I thought they would be interchangeable in some circumstances. As DI containers use Factory, I first understood DI as something that applies Factory and does some other things to decouple things in an even better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When to use Factory design pattern *instead of* Dependency Injection?

(Emphasis mine).

Never, as they aren't mutually exclusive. A factory provides an instance of an object according to a set of rules. Dependency injection tells a unit of code what its dependencies are, rather than it asking something for those dependencies. They are both providing decoupling mechanisms, and they compliment one another.

The key is to never use a static factory. Instead decouple the factory implementation from its contract (eg via an interface) and inject the factory into the unit of code that uses it.

So rather than have a method, eg

```
void Foo()
{
    var someObject = Factory.Create(someConditions);
}
```

instead, do:

```
void Foo(IFactory factory)
{
    var someObject = factory.Create(someConditions);
}
```

Comment: Note that at this point, the factory object is equivalent to a function object with signature `SomeType()`. In languages that support them, it may be better to accept a lambda. For example, in Java, take a `Supplier<SomeType>` as a parameter.

Comment: @Justin yes, I completely agree.

Answer (score 3):

David Arno's answer is upgrading you from a static factory to abstract factory. I wont argue against the added polymorphic power that gives you. But I feel compelled to point out that `Foo` still knows something about how to get `someObject`. That knowing can hold you back.

Contrast this with a [pure dependency injection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) solution:

```
class Foo {
    public Foo(SomeObject someObject) {
        this.someObject = someObject;
    }
    private SomeObject someObject; 
}


static void Main()  
{  
    // All construction code for long lived objects goes here
    SomeConditions someConditions = ...;
    Foo foo = new Foo(
        new Factory().Create(someConditions)
    );    

    // Now start the whole thing ticking 
    foo.start();

    //Since main is only called once everything built above only exists once.
}
```

Done this way `Foo` has no idea where to find `someObject`. Since it doesn't know it doesn't care. It's just as happy to take it from a factory, a new, or a test. That can end up being important.

If you go the other way and let `Foo` know about the existence of the factory you should be careful of how that can lead to the [service locator pattern](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) if you let the factory supply many dependencies. I wont tell you to never use it but be aware of how it's been [criticized](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) precisely because it spreads awareness of the locator around.

Comment: Good approach, but you still need a factory in the cases when required object can be instantiated only based on values known during runtime?

Comment: @Fabio: I think you just answered your own question. When should you use a factory over dependency injection? When an object must be instantiated based on runtime values.

Comment: @GregBurghardt true, but also some transient objects that eat to much memory and can't be allowed to loiter. But most of the time, yeah, what you said.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, I commented it, because answer suggests to move factory away to the entry point, which approach I like very much, but which will not work for the case I described.

Comment: @GregBurghardt also, just because you're using Pure DI doesn't mean you can't use a factory or any other creational pattern. Just use it before the injection so the object doesn't know about it.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified my comment. You can use DI and a factory. Just inject the factory as a dependency. The decision to use a factory at all, without regard to DI is determined more by whether or not you need runtime data, or configuration.

Comment: @GregBurghardt thats what David was showing how to do. I was showing how you can use the factory to build your dependency before injecting it into your object. By doing it that way the object has no clue how you made it, factory or not. So you can make it however you like. The object doesn't care.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to put this here as a comment, or to update my answer. So I'll start here. I completely agree with you regarding the risks of injecting a factory, especially if that factory is the container for some DI/IoC framework. However, as @Justin correctly points out on my answer, an injected factory is the semantic equivalent to injecting a function and if you do inject that function instead, then we are arguably still injecting a factory, but now we are also dealing with (potentially pure) higher ordered functions. So injecting factories is orthogonal to pure DI.

Comment: But having said all that, I completely agree that invoking the factory and then injecting the result, rather than injecting the factory itself, is often a better solution as it reduces coupling.

Comment: @DavidArno I like to only inject factories that depend on runtime data that was not available during the initial static build. The reason I lean this way is I'm trying to make my clients need for their dependencies loud and clear. I can't do that by hiding them in a locator. That doesn't mean they can't depend on, say, a timestamp factory. As for updating your answer, please feel free. I'm not going to whine about who mentioned what first. Give us the best answer you can.